# Send like a prop a attribute using v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

From parent to children, I want to send a prop.
But the attribute is define by v-for in the parent.

In this case, listItem is an array, its contains items, and each item is a object (with title attribute).

Something like:

```
<li v-for="(item, i) in listItem" :key="item.id">
    <child-component title="item['title']"></child-component>
</li>
```

I have tried:

title="item['title']"

title="item.title"

title="{{item['title']}}"

title="{{item.title}}"

Comment: I think your problem is that you need `:title="item.title"` (or whatever syntax you choose) to make it a prop. The colon at the front is important; it's shorthand for `v-bind:title` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

everytime you add "**:**" before a property, the content will be interpreted as javascript. Did you try this?

```
<li v-for="(item, i) in listItem" :key="item.id">
    <child-component :title="item.title"></child-component>
</li>
```

This may help you:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes